# Rating system (glicko, elo, etc): is 'predict the outcome of games' the same thing as 'reduce the number of upsets'?

Tags: rating, statistics, elo, mathematics, glicko

From [Lichess page 'Chess rating systems'](https://lichess.org/page/rating-systems):

Question:

> Which rating system is best?

Answer:

> The purpose of rating systems is to predict the outcome of games. Therefore, they can be objectively better or worse, according to their ability to make such predictions. Glicko 1 makes better predictions than Elo, and Glicko 2 makes better predictions than Glicko 1

My question: **Is 'predict the outcome of games' the same thing as 'reduce the number of upsets' ?**

Upset here is simply lower rating defeating (or drawing against?) higher rating. Thus, assuming all ratings are integer valued and no 2 players of equal rating play against each other, what I understand is that

'1800 is more likely (or at least as likely) to beat a 1700 if the ratings are glicko 2 as compared to glicko 1'

if and only if

'Glicko 2 makes better predictions than Glicko 1'

**Is there anything I misunderstood?**

Comment: Basically correct. (Note that these rating systems don't natively deal with draws.)

Comment: @MobeusZoom thanks! what's up with the draws please? (or do i have to make another question for this part?)

Comment: @MobeusZoom you can post as answer even if incomplete. i'll award bounty but i guess just not accept bounty. looks like no one's really answering anyway

Comment: ok. Not sure it *is* incomplete. You asked if your understanding is right, and it is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically correct. (Note that these rating systems don't natively deal with draws, only with binary wins/losses. Draws are incorporated by summarizing results as point-score = wins + 0.5 * draws.)